# How do you only scale/shrink an image horizontally with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do you get the main image to only scale/ shrink horizontally like the pics on this website? Instead of scaling the image it starts to cut out the image's sides when you resize the browser. Heres how it should work: http://castus.co.uk/

The main image on the castus.co.uk website stays at the same height no matter how small you resize the browser but it shrinks the image's sides.. I hope that explains it better :)

I can only seem to get the **whole** image to scale when I resize the browser.

I am currently using the following code for my img class:

```
    img.mail {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    }
```

Comment: They just use centred background images not actual image elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or do you mean this?

```
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('....');
    background-repeat: none;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
```

It cut instead of scale like what you have posted.

**NOTE:** You need to have wide picture to make it work prettily

Comment: You are a champion! This is how you do it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: That still scales the whole image though. The main image on the http://castus.co.uk/ website stays at the same height no matter how small you resize the browser but it shrinks the image's sides.. I hope that explains it better :)

Comment: I do not know if this is what you need, but you can use a `<div>` with a large image background centralized: `background: url ('bg.jpg') center 0 no-repeat; width: 100%; height: 500px;`

Answer (score 0):

They are using a centred background image and allowing the containing element to shrink thus hiding the sides of the image.

e.g.

```
#feature {
   background: url("path/to/img") center 0px no-repeat;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px; // Height of image
}
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xY9qT/1/

Comment: This works aswell! I appreciate your help :) Just out of interest what us the 0px for in the background line?

Comment: @ifusion That is the background shorthand, it allows you to combine `background-image`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, `background-color` into one property. The 0px is the y-position of the background (tells it to align to top). See http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/